# wordpress & divi builder not displaying the full Dubsado lead form, instead showing a scroll?

Tags: css, wordpress

There is an issue when I added the forms script (Dubsado code into wordpress page) onto the divi text section. It is just showing the 'FIRST NAME' section and other sections of the form are coming up as a scroll. Can you please help?

```
<script type="text/javascript"   src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/iframe-resizer
/3.5.14/iframeResizer.min.js">
</script><iframe src="https://hello.dubsado.com....." frameborder="0"
style="width:1px; min-width:100%;"></iframe><script 
type="text/javascript">setTimeout(function(){iFrameResize({checkOrigin: false,
heightCalculationMethod: "taggedElement"});}, 30)</script>
```

It should display the entire form on the page with 5 fields on the screen and not a scroll.

Comment: I going a workable answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20793122/iframe-height-not-working-on-wordpress-page

Comment: I found a workable answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20793122/iframe-height-not-working-on-wordpress-page